# Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty}n\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)^n = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I understand for this proof I must use the principle that I must find $N$, such that for $|u_n - 0| < \epsilon$ I have $n > N$ for $N$ that depends on $\epsilon$. However, I can't seem to get $n$ alone.

$$\left|n\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)^n\right| < \epsilon$$ led me to $$\left|\ln(n) + n(\ln(1+i) - \ln(2))\right| < \ln(\epsilon).$$ I don't know how to take this farther.

Comment: Is your $\;i\;$ the complex root of $\,-1\;$ ? And do you know something about infinite series?

Comment: Yes, $i$ is the complex root of $-1$, and I'm unsure what aspect of infinite series I could use to help.

Comment: Hint: $\left|\dfrac{1+i}{2}\right| = \dfrac{\sqrt 2}{2} < 1$.

Comment: Prove the modulus $\left|n\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)^n\right|\rightarrow0$.

Comment: @peterwhy, is that to say $|n(\frac{1+i}{2})^n| = |n||\frac{1+i}{2}|^n = |n|(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}})^n = |n|(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})^n$. From this point, would I state that $\sqrt{2}/2 < 1$, hence any number less than 1 to n as n approaches infinity approaches 0?

Comment: I suppose that would work, but how would I incorporate the formal $\epsilon - N$ proof of this?

Comment: I'm not sure if disregarding the $n$ that isn't an exponent is a good idea. if I could isolate $n$, then I will have solved this, but I'm unable to isolate it.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use (or first prove) that if $\,a_n\ge 0\;$ and decreasing monotonically to zero and $\;\sum a_n\;$ converges then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} na_n=0$$

Comment: Monotony is important here, @user37238

Comment: Monotonically decreasing and decreasing are synonyms.

Comment: I've always heard it, read and used it as "monotone decreasing/increasing", so I don't think they're synonyms, but I can't be 100% sure as english isn't my first (or second, even) language...I shall check.

Answer (score 1):

Prove the modulus $\left|n\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)^n\right|\rightarrow0$.
$$\begin{align}
\left|n\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)^n\right| <& \epsilon\\
n \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^n <& \epsilon\\
n e^{-.5n\ln2} <& \epsilon\\
-.5n(\ln2) e^{-.5n\ln2} >& -.5\epsilon\ln2\\
\end{align}$$

For small enough $\epsilon$ ($-.5\epsilon\ln2 \ge -\frac{1}{e}$, or $\epsilon\le\frac{2}{e\ln2}\approx1.06$) and large enough $n$ ($-.5n\ln2 \le -1$, or $n\ge2\ln2>1$), the left hand side can be written into $f(w)=we^w$ where $w < -1$ and $f(w) \ge -\frac{1}{e}$. There is an inverse of this function know as the lower branch of [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) $W_{-1}(x)$. The inverse function is decreasing for the domain $\left[-\frac{1}{e},0\right)$. Hence

$$\begin{align}
-.5n(\ln2) e^{-.5n\ln2} >& -.5\epsilon\ln2\\
-.5n\ln2 <& W_{-1}(-.5\epsilon\ln2)\\
n >&-\frac{2 W_{-1}(-.5\epsilon\ln2)}{\ln2}
\end{align}$$

For larger $\epsilon$ that makes $-.5\epsilon\ln2 < -\frac{1}{e}$, the inequality is always true and one can simply take $n > 0$.